# vscode - only show valid HTML emmets in suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Is there a way to show emmets only for valid HTML elements like `<h1>`, `<article>`, etc.?
Because this is kinda annoying[image]

But I'd still want to have them for valid HTML.

I tried excluding `"javascriptreact"` language in `"emmet.excludeLanguages"` but it didn't work.
I guess `"javascriptreact"` might not be a valid element of the array but I couldn't find info about what values could that array contain.

Answer (score 0):

In Emmet's settings.json file there should be the following attribute,

> ```
>     "emmet.includeLanguages": {
>     "javascript": "javascriptreact"
> },
> ```

From that remove`"javascript": "javascriptreact"`

Comment: I didn't set this setting, so it has its default values. Are you suggesting to override this setting?